# How to make a clone of ios game?

Tags: ios

I have noticed a lot of clone of different apps in the AppStore, such as rips of 2048 and flappy bird game. That's interesting for me how that could be made? Can we get the. Ode of any app on the AppStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant just get the code of any app that's in the appstore.
Most of this people just code their own version of this games, for example:
Flappy Bird, it has a really easy concept and not much gameplay so a good developer
could make a clone of that game in one day.
Another method is to buy the code of a game on one of the websites that sell code templates for apps and games.